# Error Handling: Not excepting syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error

Not showing a syntax error which i have raised as an exception in except block as to show a syntax error, its catcing the double bracket invalid syntax error and displaying invalid syntax.

```
 try:
     k=open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\lol.txt'))
     k.write("Helo World")
 except SyntaxError:
     print("There is a Syntax error")
 except OSError:
     print("The Error has OS Issues")
 finally:
     print("The Error has been specified above")
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors are thrown when the code is compiled, and a complete module is compiled before any of it executes. So well before it gets anywhere near actually executing your `try:`...`except` block.

If you want to handle a Syntax error put the code in a separate module and wrap the `try` block around the `import` statement:

```
try:
   import hello
except SyntaxError:
    print('There is a syntax error')
```

and then separately in `hello.py`:

```
k=open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\lol.txt'))
k.write("Helo World")
```

Now you'll get the expected output `There is a syntax error`